# why is async keyword added in a node function while node is already asynchronous ? why we need to tell this is an asysnchronous function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to know actual meaning of async keyword usage before function name in node js.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous in the idea that code does not need to run in the order it was called. However, you have to tell Node to do that for you.

Defining a function as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) means that the function will return a `Promise` that resolves to whatever the return of the function is:

```
// This function returns a `Promise` that resolves to `true`
const func = async () => {
  return true;
}
```

Importantly, defining a function as `async` also allows the use of the `await` keyword:

```
const func = async () => {
  const result = await fetch("someUrl");
  return await result.toJSON();
}
```

`async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for traditional Promises:

```
// This is the same function as above
const func = () => {
  return fetch("someUrl")
    .then(result => result.toJSON())
}
```

Comment: In fact `async`, in your case will produce something like
```
const func = () => {
   try{
      return fetch("someUrl").then(result=>result.toJSON());
   catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function will ALWAYS return a `promise`. If it returns a non-promise, the return value will be wrapped in `Promise.resolve`.  If it throws, it will wrap the exception in `Promise.reject`.

So the `async` keyword is a contract that guarantees the return value of the function to be asynchronus.

And this is required for the `await` keyword, because you can only `await` if you return a `promise`.